# Plotting a normal vector to a plane in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot a vector normal to a plane but it doesn't show up as normal.This is the code

`[X,Y]=meshgrid(-10:1:10);
 R=5+2*(X-4)+4*(Y-2);
 mesh(X,Y,R)
 hold
 quiver3(4,2,5,2,4,-1)
 hold off`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use surf to plot your plane, and then hold and add your velocity vector: something like: surf(X,Y,R); hold on; quiver3(4,2,5,2,4,-1) ; you can then rotate the result to see your vector (which does not look like it is normal to the plane...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector is normal to the plane. The problem is most likely the automatic axis scaling.

[image: Wrong scaling]

Use `axis equal` to ensure that data units have the same length along each axis.

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-10:1:10);
R=5+2*(X-4)+4*(Y-2);
mesh(X,Y,R)
hold
quiver3(4,2,5,2,4,-1)
hold off
axis equal
```

[image: Correct scaling]

With proper axis scaling, your normal vector will appear normal to the plane.